# .NET MAUI: How to remove space for Tab title from TabBar

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I have a .NET MAUI shell app that uses a TabBar for navigation. When I remove the title from the tabs, the space below the icon where the title should be still remains.

TabBar with Text:

[image: With text]

TabBar without Text (icons do not fill space where title was):

[image: Without Text]

How do I go about either changing the icon size or finding the corresponding property (such as `hasTitle`) that I can change?

I have tried looking through `Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml` under Shell and TabbedPage for such a property but have found nothing.

Comment: I posted an answer based on how I understand your problem. You would like to hide the navigation bar, if I understand correctly. Can you show the relevant parts of your XAML code and also a screenshot of what you are seeing to explain what you want to achieve? It will help people to better understand the issue and provide better answers. It will also make it easier in the future for others with the same or a similar question to find the right solution. Please also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ewerspej I'm new to this website so it wouldn't let me post screenshots originally, but I'm allowed to now so I added 2 to help clarify. When my tabs don't have a title, the space below the icons remains. I would like to either reduce the height of the TabBar so the icons look centered, or increase the size of the icons to fill the space below.

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. You cannot do that out-of-the-box with MAUI, unfortunately. You would need to write some platform handlers for that or switch to a different component, such as https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs which is very powerful, but incompatible with MAUI's Shell.